# Node+React+Babel+Webpack, Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

First of all, I REALLY tried to fix it myself, I found several similar questions here, but none helped me.

Getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/App.jsx
Module parse failed: D:\JS projects\habr-app\src\components\App.jsx Unexpected token (54:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render() {
|     return (
|       <div className='App'>
|         <h1>Hello World!</h1>
|         <div>
 @ ./src/client.js 3:0-42
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8050 webpack/hot/dev-server babel-polyfill ./src/client.js
```

client.js file:

```
import React      from 'react';
import ReactDOM   from 'react-dom';
import App        from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render ("<App />", document.getElementById('react-view'));
```

render function in App.jsx looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div>
          <p>Введите Ваше имя:</p>
          <div><input onChange={this.handleNameChange} /></div>
          {this.renderGreetingWidget()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

webpack.config.js file:

```
global.Promise         = require('bluebird');

var webpack            = require('webpack');
var path               = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin  = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

var publicPath         = 'http://localhost:8050/public/assets';
var cssName            = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'styles-[hash].css' : 'styles.css';
var jsName             = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'bundle-[hash].js' : 'bundle.js';

var plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      BROWSER:  JSON.stringify(true),
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin(cssName)
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  plugins.push(
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([ 'public/assets/' ], {
      root: __dirname,
      verbose: true,
      dry: false
    })
  );
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin());
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin());
}

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client.js'],
  resolve: {
    extensions:         ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
     new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
       debug: true,
       options: {
         eslint: { configFile: '.eslintrc' }
       }
     })
  ],
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/public/assets/`,
    filename: jsName,
    publicPath
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader'})
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader'})
      },
      { test: /\.gif$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif' },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg' },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png' },
      { test: /\.svg/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=26000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=1' },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'],
                          exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/] , query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'react-hot']} },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
    ]
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'source-map' : null,
  devServer: {
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
  }
};
```

The only way I can fix this problem - is to put quotes around html in render:

```
render() {
    return (
      `<div className='App'>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div>
          <p>Введите Ваше имя:</p>
          <div><input onChange={this.handleNameChange} /></div>
          {this.renderGreetingWidget()}
        </div>
      </div>`
    );
  }
```

But after that I'm gettin this error in browser and nodemon:

```
Invariant Violation: App.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

I checked and rechecked all dependencies, modules and my files.
Still, I cant find an error. Could someone help me, please?

P.S. Sorry for my awful English.

Funny thing. When I start nodemon without those quotes in App.jsx, my page loads, but without css. After that I add quotes  in file App.jsx and now webpack-devserver builds everything right, and page gets .css after refresh. JS-script still doesnt work on it, but looks almost like it should... Right until I restart nodemon... It starts to show same error "Invariant Violation: App.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object."

Comment: which line is 54 ?

Comment: @Gonzalo, its the first line with html in render function. It wants to see ` - this quote, but it ruins logic of Reactjs.

Comment: might be stupid, but using an online jsx compiler from babel https://babeljs.io/repl seems to be compiling ok. Can you see if it compiles using double quotes, instead of single quotes in the className='App' ? use className="App" instead. Just a guess, though

Comment: What babel presets are you using? you need to include react and probably stage-3

Comment: @Gonzalo. no, it doesnt work.

Comment: Could you try with: **loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=stage-3,presets[]=react']**.

Comment: are you using webpack 2 ?

Comment: Gonzalo. look, it's very funny. When I start nodemon without those quotes, my page loads, but without css. After that I add quotes ` ` in file App.jsx and now webpack-devserver builds everything right, and page gets .css after refresh. JS-script still doesnt work on it, but looks almost like it should... Right until I restart nodemon... It starts to show same error "Invariant Violation: App.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object."

Comment: @Hosar, yes, webpack 2.

Comment: In webpack2 you don't pass the parameters in the query string. Instead use **query** section.

Comment: is like this: `{test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,exclude: /node_modules/,use: ['babel-loader'],query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}}`

Comment: @Hosar, I've tried all the combinations. None worked out.

Comment: This is how it looks like now: {test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader?presets[]=stage-3,presets[]=react'],query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}},

Comment: @Hosar, and this way it doesnt work too {test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'],query: {presets: ['stage-3', 'es2015', 'react']}},

Comment: try without `react-hot-loader` maybe is causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you did not define a loader that can handle JSX, although it might look like you did in your webpack config. The problem is that you define both `module.rules` and `module.loaders`. When webpack sees `module.rules` it ignores `module.loaders` completely (though it still exists for compatibility reason). The fix is simple, just put all loaders under `module.rules`.

And there is also a problem in your `.jsx?` rule, because `query` (which is also deprecated and replaced with [`options`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-options-rule-query)) cannot be used for an array of loaders, but instead should be defined per loader in the array. Since you did it inline as string you don't need it at all.

To get a working config replace the `module` section with:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader'})
    },
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader'})
    },
    { test: /\.gif$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif' },
    { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg' },
    { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png' },
    { test: /\.svg/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=26000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
    { test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=1' },
    { test: /\.jsx?$/, use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'],
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/] },
    { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
  ]
},
```

In case you decide to use `options`, which is definitely more readable, your `.jsx?` rule would look like this:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  use: [
    'react-hot-loader',
    { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['react', 'es2015'] } },
  ],
  exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
}
```

As shown in the docs for [use](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-use).

Comment: thanks for full explanation, I'll try it tonight. My problem was that i used tutorial, where webpack 1 was used, but tried to remake it for webpack 2.

Comment: In that case you should also read the official [Migration Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/).